# Inserting database output into specific div tags

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form set up, and I want the user to be able to enter information and then select via radio buttons which div the database will output the inserted data into. Right now I have it set up to where the user can input his information, and the information will be output into a div, but i'm trying to figure out how I would go about inserting data from the 1 database into different divs. For example:

```
The user inserts: Hello World
```

and it is input in to the database and displayed in `div1`, but then later the user decides to input "How are you?" and that be displayed in `div2` and you would have something that looks like

```
     |    div1      |     |      div2    |
     | Hello World  |     | How are you? |
```

Do I need to create 2 separate tables within my database that correspond with my respective div tags? What is the simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table where column='column'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 if($row['id']=="Hello World")
    {
     echo "<div id='div1'>".$$row['id']."</div>";
    }
 else if($row['id']=="How are you?")
    {
      echo "<div id='div2'>".$$row['id']."</div>";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to up if you used it. Thanks @Jcmoney1010

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

- Perhaps the most logical and correct way is to have one table with the following columns: `user_id`, `div_name`, and `text`
- Another way would be to have one table and a `user_id`, `div1`, and `div2` table
- As you mentioned, you *could* have two tables both with the structure `user_id`, `text` where the determination of which div it is for is in the table name but this is not good form and I'd suggest against it.